# LogCat: Time in Brackets

Tags: android, android-logcat

I'm trying to understand an Android custom view that extends `SeekBar`. It has a method called `handleClick` that obviously handles clicks. I put a log expression there and played around with the SeekBar. The `LogCat` looks like this:

```
        08-29 06:42:30.992    1037-1037/mypackage.debug D/STEP﹕ handleclick id 4 text 10
        08-29 06:42:31.008    1037-1037/mypackage.debug D/STEP﹕ handleclick id 4 text 10
        08-29 06:42:31.024    1037-1037/mypackage.debug D/STEP﹕ handleclick id 4 text 10
        08-29 06:42:31.060    1037-1037/mypackage.debug D/STEP﹕ handleclick id 4 text 10
        08-29 06:42:31.092    1037-1037/mypackage.debug D/STEP﹕ handleclick id 3 text 5
        08-29 06:42:31.216    1037-1037/mypackage.debug D/﹕ [ 08-29 06:42:31.224  1037: 1037 D/STEP     ]    handleclick id 3 text 5
```

**My question is**: why does the last line look different from the others? What's the time in brackets and why does it differ from the first timestamp in that line?

Here's the method with my Log statement:

```
private void handleClick(Dot selected) {

    Log.d("STEP", "handleclick id " + selected.id + " text " + selected.text);

    if ((prevSelected == null) || (prevSelected.equals(selected) == false)) {
        if (mItemClickListener != null) {
            mItemClickListener.onItemClick(null, this, selected.id, selected.id);
        }
        prevSelected = selected;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like a LogCat bug to me. I see this from time to time and just ignore it.